# How can I recognize NODE_ENV in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express for framework.

And I would like to divide my configuration to "development" and "production".

I know that I can use

```
app.configure('development', function() {});
app.configure('production', function() {});
```

But I want to know the way actually how I can know what the NODE_ENV value is.

I tried to find in global variables but I could not find.

I really need this to use other Database configuration depends on NODE_ENV

in my database config.js file.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have found the answer

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Comment: in node, `process` is a thing, no `require` needed.

Answer (score 8):

Express also exposes this data via `app.settings.env`

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively ...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('env');
```